Play console policy issue Update com.google.android.play
i got this update play service issue when i tried to upload my new build version 1.0.3
play console update library issue i am unable to get that i am not using the feature library in my build. Gradle but still getting this error https://i.sstatic.net/kEBclIUb.png)
How to fix this violation

i resolve this issue by checking my build.gradle dependencies one of them is using internally play-feature library
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7")
this library is using internally
com.google.android.play:feature-delivery-ktx:2.0.1
which is not supported android 14 targetSDKversion.
my androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment library is update with stable version so i have to add the new dependecies
com.google.android.play:feature-delivery-ktx:2.1.0 with new version 2.1.0 in future may be the androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment library got the update with latest play-features library
Here is some additional library which also cause the same error please update the library with latest version or same so you can resolve this error
Here are some addtional library :-1
And  for now these library is not update yet so you need to add the play-feature library manually in your build. Gradle
androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7 com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-module-support:16.0.0-beta03  com.genexus.android:DynamicFeaturesLib:2.3.1 

Tried the above approach but it did not work, so I added the libs below and it fixed the issue.
com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0
com.google.android.play:feature-delivery-ktx:2.1.0

then navigation
androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7


it works, tnanks
